# TeXmaker: Need syntax highlight for command in black color

Tags: texmaker

I saw almost everyone who uses TeXmaker has syntax highlight, why I don't ?

I have used the default in `option`->`editor`

The others:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
```

my: I need **not black color for below command**

`\documentclass[11pt]{article}`

Comment: emm, the stackexchange makes the second one having red 'documentclass' but in real environment it is black

Comment: You can wrap your comment into your post.  What is your question about?  I don't understand how document class is related to highlighting.

Comment: option->Configure-->editor: use same [colorhexa value](http://www.colorhexa.com/000000) as in `Text`= `#000000` -->Black in `LaTeX command`= `#000000` instead of default `#800000` maroon

Comment: @dustin That is an example that the others have "\documentclass", which is a Latex command cherry, but I have it black. I want to change the black into another color.

Comment: @texenthusiast I tried to change the value of Latex command, but it does seem to change at all.

Comment: Did you press `OK` button after pasting the black hexa `#000000` ,It reflected the highlighting immediately for me on atleast on Linux. I cannot test it on Windows now

Comment: @texenthusiast after restart the Texmaker, your method works. :) if still fails I would restart the computer. Windows, you know... Thank you

Comment: choose the http://www.colorhexa.com/color-names you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments converted into answer to make this thread answered:

Open TeXmaker and set `option`->`Configure`-->`editor`: use same [colorhexa value](http://www.colorhexa.com/000000) as in Text= `#000000` --> Black in LaTeX command= `#000000` instead of default `#800000` maroon

Sometimes `TeXmaker` might need a Restart to take the Syntax highlighting into effect.

choose the color schemes you wish using hexa code at http://www.colorhexa.com/color-names